# weather service provider with waves height data?

Tags: api, weather, yahoo-weather-api, google-weather-api

I'm not sure this is the right place for this question, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm looking for an API to get Waves height data for a surfing application I'm writing. I have no idea where can I find such a provider. Does Yahoo provide this kind of services? do they give you waves height information?

Also it has to have support for worldwide weather data.

thank you for any help.

Comment: If anyone else is finding this, we released our api called Storm Glass a couple of months back. Includes wave height, period and direction(and other attributes). https://stormglass.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the [National Data Buoy Center](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov), which collects wave height data worldwide with a focus on the US coast. They offer many ways to consume their data including KML download.

Comment: @Yosi199 If anyone else is finding this, we released our api called Storm Glass a couple of months back. Includes wave height, period and direction(and other attributes). https://stormglass.io